# Error: "Type '*' does not conform to protocol '*'" using custom class and NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop, protocols

> I know there are many questions and answers for this `does not conform to protocol`error, but nothing matched and/or worked for my specific problem.

I really don't know, what I'm doing wrong. I wanted to divide my code into classes so i can separate my "backend" from my "frontend" (ViewController.swift).

In this case, I want a class which handles the API call in the background, so i created a `ApiController.swift` file with the following code:

```swift
import Foundation


protocol OMDbApiControllerProtocol {
    func didReceiveOMDbResults(results: Dictionary<String, String>)
}

class OMDbApiController {

    var delegate: OMDbApiControllerProtocol?

    init(delegate: OMDbControllerProtocol?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func searchOMDb(forSeries: String, season: String, episode: String) {

        let term = forSeries.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        if let escapedTerm = term.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

            let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(escapedTerm)")
            println(url!)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in

                var jsonResults = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as? Dictionary<String, String>

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   self.delegate?.didReceiveOMDbResults(jsonResults!)
                }

            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }

}
```

Then I "imported" the protocol in the `ViewController.swift` file:

```swift
class SeriesInfoViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, OMDbApiControllerProtocol
```

**This creates the error:** Type 'SeriesInfoViewController' does not conform to protocol 'OMDbApiControllerProtocol'

> I hope you understand my problem and please considerate, that this is my first asked question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you kind of misunderstood how your protocol should be used. By 'importing' the protocol you are saying that your class actually conforms to that protocol. In this case that would mean that `SeriesInfoViewController` has to implement `didReceiveOMDbResults` in order to actually conform to the protocol.

So if you implement that method you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. So simple :D Is there a better way to do this? Without protocols?

Comment: You could just skip the protocol altogether and make your delegate of type `SeriesInfoViewController`. The obvious downside would be that you lose all flexibility in terms of who can be a delegate. A protocol ensures that whatever you pass as a delegate will implement certain methods so that you can safely call them. In short, yes there are (possibly) simpler ways to do it but a protocol is the best, most reliable way to ensure that a delegate has a certain method available.